# System root not enough space remaining

Tags: partitioning, nvidia, disk-usage, cuda

I was trying to install CUDA on my Ubuntu 18.04 while an alert like this occurs  `Not enough space remaining on system root` . So I ran following to check:

```
danni@danni:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             7888196         0   7888196   0% /dev
tmpfs            1584380      2024   1582356   1% /run
/dev/sda6       19092136  15497852   2601416  86% /
tmpfs            7921884     26480   7895404   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            7921884         0   7921884   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop3         35584     35584         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
/dev/loop2         21504     21504         0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/25
/dev/loop1          2432      2432         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/180
/dev/loop0         13312     13312         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/101
/dev/loop5        296064    296064         0 100% /snap/pycharm-professional/78
/dev/loop6        143488    143488         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/59
/dev/loop9         13312     13312         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/103
/dev/loop8          3840      3840         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
/dev/loop10         3456      3456         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36
/dev/loop12         1664      1664         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/154
/dev/loop4         14848     14848         0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/37
/dev/loop11        89088     89088         0 100% /snap/core/4830
/dev/loop14       144384    144384         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
/dev/loop13        12544     12544         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/69
/dev/loop15       307200    307200         0 100% /snap/pycharm-professional/68
/dev/loop19         2432      2432         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/178
/dev/loop20         5120      5120         0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/41
/dev/loop16        89088     89088         0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop18         3840      3840         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/45
/dev/loop17       142848    142848         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/64
/dev/sda7       33186512  16828492  14642516  54% /home
tmpfs            1584376        20   1584356   1% /run/user/120
tmpfs            1584376        48   1584328   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop21        89088     89088         0 100% /snap/core/5145
/dev/sda3      293601276    133692 293467584   1% /media/danni/New Volume
/dev/sda2      314572796    134332 314438464   1% /media/danni/New Volume1
/dev/sda1      314572796    809720 313763076   1% /media/danni/New Volume2
/dev/sdb2      122947924 121239492   1708432  99% /media/danni/388CA9278CA8E09C
```

Then my disk usage looks like following:
[disk usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhSCl.png)

SO I really do not know why there're so many `/media` folders or `dev/loop`. Can someone please explain this to me or tell me how to free up more space? Is there a relatively convenient way to change disk space? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The root partition is just too small, about 19GB or so. Either remove something, or better, repartition, and allocate more space.

Comment: @mikewhatever thanks. Would you say using `sudo apt install gparted` as the best method?

Comment: `gparted` won't be able to change the size of a mounted partition.  It's far easier to boot a 'live' system and do it from there

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for your suggestion. I'm kinda new to Linux administration so pardon me for rookie questions. Booting from a 'live' system means using CD or USB stick right? does that mean I have to back up all files I have now and all the system files& installed software will be erased?

Comment: @guiverc Also I just checked my disk usage using `gparted` and all my media folders that have a lot of free space are partitioned as `dev/sda1` or `dev/sda2` , which I tried, can be unmounted. But my `root` is in `dev/sda6` located under a higher-hierarchy `dev/sda4`. Does this mean I cannot allocate free space to `root` and booting from live system is the only option?

Comment: Yep, you can use a Ubuntu install media (desktop versions anyway) when you select 'try ubuntu' switches to a live system. Yes of course; you're changing partitions and moving data so a backup should be performed, however if all goes well you'll not need it, but better safe than sorry.  It shouldn't impact anything, except you may need to re-setup grub (so stage 1 or the MBR points to stages 1.5-2 which are in /boot, as their location on disk may change)